# Tackling a network issue with git clone --recursive

Tags: git, networking, github, git-submodules, git-clone

I am unable to clone git repositories with submodules.

$ git clone --recursive https://www.github.com/lagadic/visp_auto_tracker.git

Cloning into 'visp_auto_tracker'...
remote: Counting objects: 275, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (222/222), done.
remote: Total 275 (delta 154), reused 157 (delta 42)
Receiving objects: 100% (275/275), 44.52 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (154/154), done.
Submodule 'flashcode_mbt' (git://github.com/lagadic/flashcode_mbt.git) registered for path 'flashcode_mbt'
Cloning into 'flashcode_mbt'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out

Clone of 'git://github.com/lagadic/flashcode_mbt.git' into submodule path 'flashcode_mbt' failed.

This happens on UbuntuLTS12.04 git version 1.7.9.5 as well as Fedora17 git version 1.7.11.7.

It seems to be a network issue for sure. Because i asked other users on different networks to do it and it works. Any of you faced a similar problem? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to open port `9418` for TCP in/TCP out

You also might need to set your global user using `git config --global user.name <your_name>` if you haven't already.

Comment: It was 9418 indeed. Most probably it has nothing to do with username